# Sitecore GeoIP service with zipcode

Tags: geo-location

We have a need to detect the user location at the Zipcode level and present him with personalized content. We are looking to see if Sitecore GeoIP service with 8.1 supports Zipcode accuracy?

Please let me know if anyone has worked with GeoIP service at Zipcode and % of accuracy that we get?

Answer (score 3):

The GeoIP service can be made to resolve at zipcode level. That said; you cannot rely on it to personalize your content for your visitor - real time. For that you need to look at other options - like creating your own MaxMind integration or looking at other alternatives.

See also: [Sitecore IP Geo location Service-Personalization with Geo-based conditions does not work](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/sitecore-ip-geo-location-service-personalization-with-geo-based-conditions-does)

Comment: Thanks Mark, If we implement using local database rather than real-time service how do we manage to keep it updated?

Comment: Well. IP information doesn't change _that_ frequently. If you subscribe to the data via for instance MaxMind; I propose that someone download an updated dataset every 1 or even 3 months or so. Depending on how keen you are to be fully updated for every request.

Comment: Do bear in mind IPs are not the most reliable thing to locate mobile devices.