# Specific Rules to exclude Geo Locations

Tags: geo-location

We are working on personalize the content based on Geo location. We have requirement not to show specific content for some locations.

Are there any rules or any other ways available to exclude any specific location for some content(e.g. Country, State, City etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore has several rules available for setting up personalization based on geo information (e.g. City, Country, Region, ...). You can read all about it [here on the doc site](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/ip_geolocation/getting_started_with_sitecore_ip_geolocation_service#_Personalize_site_pages). With those rules and the personalization functionality to hide components this is possible.

Make sure to read this [thread](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/sitecore-ip-geo-location-service-personalization-with-geo-based-conditions-does/1053) as well though.