# Sitecore:9 geo location presentation rule based rendering not working

Tags: geo-location

I am using Sitecore-9 with Sitecore-IP-Geolocation-Service enabled.

I have a rendering based on presentation rule as follows:

1. **Where country == United states** means we are showing unauthenticated rendering.
2. If its other countries we are showing main rendering.

Below rule based rendering.

[image]

3. Issue is what ever country I gave in the rules condition always fails.
4. Even I tested with TestIp page. Its showing correct location information.

[image]

5. Even I tried country code concepts, explained in below link. This also 
   has fails for all the country-codes.
   Ref: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1570/2311

**How to validate the rules with which country it is taking and why our rules getting failed.**

Comment: Can you check this article https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/azure-appgateways-and-sitecores-use-of-x-forwarded-for/ ?

Comment: Rule takes country from Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.GeoData.Country. Make sure that tracker GeoData is filled and country is equal to US.