# What's the best way to get the current Contact's location?

Tags: contact-facets, contact

I'm trying to get the current Contact's location info for personalization purposes.  I've seen that GEO IP is not a good way, and the only other place I see is in ExperienceForms database where we collect City, State, and Zipcode, but those records do not have Contact ID. I could query FieldData to get records with the current Contact's email, then query FormEntry for their most current entry, then re-query FieldData to get all the fields for that entry and get the location info from that, but I'm thinking it's going to be too processing intensive.  Is there an approach that I'm not thinking of for this?

This is for Sitecore 9.1.1 btw.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: What's wrong with Geo IP? On a Country level is it pretty accurate. Or do you need City level? City level accuracy isn't great.

Comment: Right, it's accuracy and processing time according to this post - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/sitecore-ip-geo-location-service-personalization-with-geo-based-conditions-does

Answer (score 1):

In order to get around this drawback on one of our projects we have relied on Akamai to send the user location(in our case the country) and we would do personalization based on this data instead of sitecore geo ip location. I think this can be achieved with other cdns aswell, like cloudfare.

Unfortunately if you can't use any cdn the other options would be the ones described in the sitecore KB https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/320734

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Submit action for your Form to feed location details in to the current contact and then use it on Rules engine.
You might have to build a few custom personalisation conditions.

Haven't tried this but should be doable.