# How to get postal code with GeosIp service

Tags: geo-location

Using XP 10.1 & the GeoIp service.
I would like to get the Postal code of the visitor to execute some business logic and this is not for Personalization.

With the following code, I am able to get the latitude, longitude and the Country name, but all the other properties are null.

```
var latitude = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault(0);
var longitude = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault(0);
var contactLocation = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData;
```

Is it possible to get the postal code with GeoIp service.

Comment: Regardless of whether you use this for personalisation or your own code, this still applies https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/sitecore-ip-geo-location-service-personalization-with-geo-based-conditions-does

Answer (score 1):

The data is definitely there. But the IP you are current using, Sitecore does not have the granular data for it. Try from a different IP.

```
"GeoData": {
  "AreaCode": "N/A",
  "BusinessName": "Comcast Cable",
  "City": "Shelburne",
  "Country": "US",
  "Dns": "comcast.net",
  "Isp": "Comcast Cable",
  "Latitude": 44.2923,
  "Longitude": -73.3148,
  "MetroCode": "523",
  "PostalCode": "05482",
  "Region": "VT",
  "Url": "N/A"
},
```